# How to get latest eloquent relationship by column name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am building a small application on `Laravel 5.6` where I am having two models `Project` and `Status`. In this I am having a relation as such:

In **Project** Model I am having:

```php
public function statusUpdate()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Status','project_id','id');

}
```

and to retrieve latest status I have:

```php
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status','project_id','id')->latest();
}
```

In status I have columns: `date`, `status`, `sub_status`, `comments`.

I want to retrieve `Status` where I am having `latest status` by `date` mentioned in the column

I tried doing this in my model:

```php
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status','project_id','id')->latest('date');
}
```

But this thing is not working out, help me out in this. Thanks

**edit**

I am using this relation in eager loading something like this:

```php
Project::when( $request->name , function( $q) use( $request ) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name .'%');
})->with('latestStatus')
    ->orderBy($request->sort_by_col, $request->order_by)
    ->paginate(30);
```

Comment: How are you using `latestStatus()`? With eager loading?

Comment: have you tried using the following `statusUpdate()->latest()`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes. That is main problem.

Comment: Please post that code.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir question updated.

Comment: What does "is not working out" mean?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I am unable to sort by `date` column, I am getting sorted by `created_at`

Comment: Do you want to sort `projects` by `latestStatus.date`?

Comment: Can you upload your `Status` model.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No, I want to get status sorted with date in descending order and get the first/latest status so that I can eager load with project model.

Comment: `->latest('date')` works for me. What result are you getting?

Comment: @Mahbub I have only fillables and table as protect variables. and a reverse relation: `public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','project_id','id');
    }`

Comment: Can you log the queries with `\DB::enableQueryLog(); [...] dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use orderBy in the relationship.

```
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status','project_id','id')->orderBy('date', 'desc');
}
```

Try it out.

Comment: This has `hasOne` relation will it `order` by `date` in `desc`?

Comment: @NitishKumar Yes, It will.

Comment: `->orderBy('date', 'desc')` is equivalent to `->latest('date')`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I didn't know that. When I tried `latest('date')` it's not working. I don't know what's wrong with `latest('date')` but `orderBy('date', 'desc')` is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You got your models wrong. This is what should be in the Project model

```
public function statuses() //plural because a project has many statuses
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Status','id','project_id');
}
```

If you want the latest status, call this in your controller:

```
Project::where('name', 'like', "%{$request->name}%")->with('statuses', function($q) {
  return $q->orderBy('date', $request->order_by);
})->paginate(30);
```

If you want the latest project where the status has changed, first the Status model:

```
public function project() 
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Project','project_id','id');
}
```

And in your controller:

```
$project = Status::latest()->first()->project;
```

Comment: You misunderstood the whole question. I want project with latest status as relation. I don't want the latest status with projects. Please go through my question once again.

Answer (score -1):

Add `first` to the end of the query.

```
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status','project_id','id')->latest()->first();
}
```

This is how it works

1. The `statusUpdate` method builds the query and does the setup for has many relationship
2. The `latest` method adds the order by clause
3. The `first` methods adds the `limit 1` clause, then executes the query and returns the first result

Comment: first() method doesn't add limit 1 to the query. First is retrieve all the record and then return the first one.

Comment: @RutvijKothari, no, first() from the query builder does add limit 1.  `get()->first()` would be what you're thinking of.   However, this answer does not answer the question, it actually limits functionality because it is no longer returning a relationship.

Comment: @Devon Thanks for the clarification. I appreciate that. :) I thought first() works like this get()->first() but good to know that.